# How to Upload Pictures to Be Saved For Later

Tags: database, image, web, native, cdn

This seems like it should be a simple question, and I apologize if this is stupid to ask, but I have been scouring seemingly every corner of the web and still have absolutely no idea how to even begin saving pictures.
For my specific case, I am working in React Native and an important function of the app is to take pictures and save them in a manner where an admin account can later access those images.
I sincerely have no idea how to do this. I know you *can* through AWS S3 Buckets, but I've heard nothing but bad stuff about them, ad my current experience on AWS is pretty rough so I'd prefer avoiding that. I tried something called contentful, but never was able to determine how to connect to the API from inside my code. Supabase was another option, but the Client simply refused to work, and it still seemed overly complicated and i wasn't easily able to find any JS code that would upload. Now I'm working with Cloudify and I was able to find the code needed to upload pictures to it... but I have no idea how to create an account with the proper storage / organization and then extrapolate the information later. I feel like this shouldn't be as convoluted as it is, does anyone have any suggestions, ideas, or experience with Cloudify?

Answer (score 0):

try firebase from google. fireship (name similarity coincidence) channel on youtube has convinient and easy to understand tutorials about firebase.